# Find the last index of a character in a string

Tags: string, lua

I want to have ability to use a `lastIndexOf` method for the strings in my Lua (Luvit) project. Unfortunately there's no such method built-in and I'm bit stuck now.

In Javascript it looks like:

```
'my.string.here.'.lastIndexOf('.')     // returns 14
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: I think simplest way is just use `string.find` `('my.string.here.'):find("%.[^.]-$")`. but you need escape special chars (e.g. `.`, `*`, `+` etc.). Also in Lua result should be 15.

Comment: @moteus nice suggestion, but I wanted common solution (finding index for numbers as well, for example)

Comment: @lhf Why do you even ask? First and last index of string in substring are widely used functions accross all programming languages! There's no need for him to explain any specific problem...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function findLast(haystack, needle)
    local i=haystack:match(".*"..needle.."()")
    if i==nil then return nil else return i-1 end
end
s='my.string.here.'
print(findLast(s,"%."))
print(findLast(s,"e"))
```

Note that to find `.` you need to escape it.

Answer (score 4):

To search for the last instance of string `needle` in `haystack`:

```
function findLast(haystack, needle)
    --Set the third arg to false to allow pattern matching
    local found = haystack:reverse():find(needle:reverse(), nil, true)
    if found then
        return haystack:len() - needle:len() - found + 2 
    else
        return found
    end
end

print(findLast("my.string.here.", ".")) -- 15, because Lua strings are 1-indexed
print(findLast("my.string.here.", "here")) -- 11
print(findLast("my.string.here.", "there")) -- nil
```

If you want to search for the last instance of a pattern instead, change the last argument to `find` to `false` (or remove it).

Comment: Your example returns `1` for me.

Comment: Sorry, from memory - I must have forgotten how Lua strings work.

Comment: I've tested it also with empty strings. Works flawlessly. I like this more than other solutions because it's simple and clever.

Answer (score 4):

If you have performance concerns, then this might be a bit faster if you're using Luvit which uses LuaJIT.

```
local find = string.find
local function lastIndexOf(haystack, needle)
    local i, j
    local k = 0
    repeat
        i = j
        j, k = find(haystack, needle, k + 1, true)
    until j == nil

    return i
end

local s = 'my.string.here.'
print(lastIndexOf(s, '.')) -- This will be 15.
```

Keep in mind that Lua strings begin at `1` instead of `0` as in JavaScript.

Comment: found this interesting post regarding performance - https://neil.fraser.name/news/2009/12/25/, just curiosity did this answer copes with performance - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20460403/2117550 ?

Comment: @Kosmetika Interesting indeed. I hadn't seen it before, but what I wrote is very close to `lastIndexOfFind`. The only big difference is that my function returns `nil` as opposed to `-1`, which is more Lua style. Oh, and my function picks up from the second return value of `string.find`, which means it skips some unnecessary substrings and is theoretically faster. I believe @lhf's answer is more performant on plain Lua and less so on LuaJIT 2.1 due to `string.match` not being compiled yet but fixed pattern `string.find` is, but you'll have to perform your own tests for your use case.

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a solution using
[LPeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/)’s position capture.

```
local lpeg      = require "lpeg"
local Cp, P     = lpeg.Cp, lpeg.P
local lpegmatch = lpeg.match

local cache = { }

local find_last = function (str, substr)
  if not (str and substr)
    or str == "" or substr == ""
  then
    return nil
  end
  local pat = cache [substr]
  if not pat then
    local p_substr   = P (substr)
    local last       = Cp() * p_substr * Cp() * (1 - p_substr)^0 * -1
    pat = (1 - last)^0 * last
    cache [substr] = pat
  end
  return lpegmatch (pat, str)
end
```

`find_last()` finds the last occurence of *substr* in the string
*str*, where *substr* can be a string of any length.
The first return value is the position of the first character of
*substr* in *str*, the second return value is the position of the
first character following *substr* (i.e. it equals the length of the
match plus the first return value).

Usage:

```
local tests = {
  A    = [[fooA]],                      --> 4, 5
  [""] = [[foo]],                       --> nil
  FOO  = [[]],                          --> nil
  K    = [[foo]],                       --> nil
  X    = [[X foo X bar X baz]],         --> 13, 14
  XX   = [[foo XX X XY bar XX baz X]],  --> 17, 19
  Y    = [[YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY]],        --> 18, 19
  ZZZ  = [[ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ]],        --> 14, 17
  --- Accepts patterns as well!
  [P"X" * lpeg.R"09"^1] = [[fooX42barXxbazX]], --> 4, 7
}

for substr, str in next, tests do
  print (">>", substr, str, "->", find_last (str, substr))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be optimized but simple and does the work.

```
function lastIndexOf(haystack, needle)
  local last_index = 0
  while haystack:sub(last_index+1, haystack:len()):find(needle) ~= nil do
    last_index = last_index + haystack:sub(last_index+1, haystack:len()):find(needle)
  end
  return last_index
end

local s = 'my.string.here.'
print(lastIndexOf(s, '%.')) -- 15
```