# Why does this Lua code return an index?

Tags: string, lua, match

I found this Lua in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20460403/258523) by lhf to a question on finding the index of the last occurrence of a string (needle) in another string (haystack)....

```
function findLast(haystack, needle)
  local i=haystack:match(".*"..needle.."()")
  if i==nil then return nil else return i-1 end
end
s='my.string.here.'
print(findLast(s,"%."))
print(findLast(s,"e"))
```

You'd think I'd be happy to have found the answer I wanted to my original question but I'm afraid I like to know not only that the answer works (and it does work for all inputs I tried) but why it works ;-)

The trouble is I can't find any Lua documentation which states the behaviour for s:match returning an index within a string when the capture does not define a pattern.

Can anyone point me in the direction of something which confirms this is defined and expected behaviour and not just a nice coincidence that it happens to work?

Comment: Generally a good idea (I believe) to link the actual answer you are referencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in the manual. The section on [Patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1)

> As a special case, the empty capture () captures the current string position (a number). For instance, if we apply the pattern "()aa()" on the string "flaaap", there will be two captures: 3 and 5.

Comment: Yeah, good point - the original answer was [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459943/find-the-last-index-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - although I must have read the section on Patterns loads of times by now I didn't recall that bit. I expected to see the behaviour defined in the function docs, not as an integral part of the pattern stuff. Lua internals exposed - thanks again.